# SpriteKit detecting non-existent contact

Tags: sprite-kit, physics, skphysicsbody

SpriteKit is reporting contact where none exists. I set a breakpoint in didBeginContact and found this:

```
(lldb) po contact.bodyA <SKPhysicsBody> type:<Rectangle> representedObject:[<SKSpriteNode> name:'5' texture:[<SKTexture> 'Brick_3.png' (60 x 60)] position:{600, 120} size:{60, 60} rotation:0.00]

(lldb) po contact.bodyB <SKPhysicsBody> type:<Rectangle> representedObject:[<SKSpriteNode> name:'bullet' texture:['nil'] position:{568.67426, 86.000015} size:{15, 8} rotation:0.00]

(lldb) p bodyB.usesPreciseCollisionDetection (BOOL) $10 = YES
```

BodyA is not moving.
BodyB is running an action that moves it in the positive X direction. Its y value is not changing.

Can anybody tell why it would think these 2 bodies are in contact?

Comment: Fixed. The problem was that bodyA.node uses (0,0) as its anchorPoint. So, the SKphysicsBody for the node was centered there. Using bodyWithRectangleOfSize:center: does not work (A bug in SpriteKit?)  Instead, I used bodyWithPolygonFromPath:(CGPathRef)path to create the SKPhysicsBody.

Comment: The rectangleofSize:center: method does work. Maybe if you post how you have implemented it, we may be able to tell you where you are going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, akashg. I went to construct an example of the problem I had with bodyWithRectangleOfSize:center: and it worked fine. So, I went back into my code and tried it and it worked there, too. I don't know what I did wrong when I tried it before. But I'm using it now instead of the bodyWithPolygonFromPath: resulting in simpler code. So, thanks.